# Centering vertical aligned expressions respect to a part of a final expression

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, alignment, center

I tried my best with the title by I think it's still unclear what I mean (any suggestions are welcome), anyway I'll make sense of it here.

I'm trying to center two "little" expressions, each on a different row, respect to a part of a bigger expression, like this:

[image: Stacked expressions]

This is my code

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! [\varphi] \\
& \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \vdots \\
\frac{\psi}{\varphi \rightarrow \psi} \ \mathrm{I} \! \to
\end{aligned}
$$
```

As you can see the little expressions are `[\varphi]` and `\vdots`, the big expression is `\frac{\psi}{\varphi \rightarrow \psi} \ \mathrm{I} \! \to`, the part of the big expression that I take as "center" is just the `frac`.

Now I have to do this for many other expressions and since my code is just a workaround it can't be reused easily, is there a more scalable way of doing this? Some environment I'm missing?

Comment: delete all the `\!` and use `\begin{gather*}` not `$$\begin{aligned}` (`$$` should never be used in latex)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If the question were about just this expression, I would suggest `array`, with the "right hand" part of the last line entered with `\rlap` matched with a `phantom` of equal size on the left.  But not knowing how it's embedded in a larger expression, that could be way off base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest you (a) encase the `\ \mathrm{I}\to` part in a `\mathrlap` directive (provided by the `mathtools` package) to make it take up zero width and (b) use either a `matrix` or a `gathered` environment (depending on whether you want to employ text-style or display-style math mode) to encase the full column vector of items.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathrlap' macro

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix} % use text-style math mode for rows
  [\varphi] \\
  \vdots \\
  \dfrac{\psi}{\varphi \rightarrow \psi} \mathrlap{\ \mathrm{I}\to}
\end{matrix} \hphantom{\ \mathrm{I}\to} % make up the invisible spacing
\qquad
\begin{gathered} % use display-style math mode for rows
  [\varphi] \\
  \vdots \\
  \frac{\psi}{\varphi \rightarrow \psi} \mathrlap{\ \mathrm{I}\to}
\end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}
```